# query via caml in sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, asp.net

hello I'm doing a query caml in asp.net c # to search by user of my column "users" that I have but only works with a single user, and when I change user and enter another brings me all the users I have and not the that I introduced in specific
please help me I have my colsulta wrong? What I want is for me to filter by the user who enters

[image: This is my query]

[image: This is my column Users]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single User Text field should use Eq condition:

```
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List spList = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Empleados");
            ctx.Load(spList);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            if (spList != null && spList.ItemCount > 0)
            {
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
                camlQuery.ViewXml =
                   @"<View>  
                            <Query> 
                               <Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Usuario' /><Value Type='Text'>jerry@testlz.onmicrosoft.com</Value></Eq></Where> 
                            </Query> 
                            <RowLimt>100</RowLimit>
                      </View>";

                ListItemCollection listItems = spList.GetItems(camlQuery);
                ctx.Load(listItems);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                foreach (ListItem item in listItems)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item["Usuario"]);
                }
```

For multiple user text, use Or, And Condition, here is a sample code for your reference with Or:

```
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List spList = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Empleados");
    ctx.Load(spList);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    if (spList != null && spList.ItemCount > 0)
    {
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.ViewXml =
           @"<View>  
                    <Query> 
                       <Where><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='Usuario' /><Value Type='Text'>xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Usuario' /><Value Type='Text'>xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com</Value></Eq></Or></Where> 
                    </Query> 
                    <RowLimt>100</RowLimit>
              </View>";

        ListItemCollection listItems = spList.GetItems(camlQuery);
        ctx.Load(listItems);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach (ListItem item in listItems)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item["Usuario"]);
        }
    }
```

Reference about condition of Caml Query:

[CAML Query with Multiple Conditions](https://aasai-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2013/02/caml-query-with-multiple-conditions.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have "greater or equal to". You probably want "equal to" or other comparison.

Comment: thank you very much friends I will try your solutions immediately

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Users column is of type string, you can use below query.

For Single User

```
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery(); 
string camqueryStr = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Usuario'/>" + "<Value Type='Text'>" + <**youruseremailladdress**> +  "</Value></Eq></Where></Query><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>";
```

For multiple User with OR condition, you might need to loop through and create dynamic query.

```
List<string> users= new List<string>(); // assuming contains users email address, populate this list with users email address
string camlquery = "<View><Query><Where>";

// Make sure to update column name as per your list
camlquery += "<In><FieldRef Name='Usuario' />"; 
camlquery += "<Values>";

foreach (var user in users)
{
    camlquery += "<Value Type='Text'>" + user + "</Value>";
}

camlquery += "</Values></In></Where></Query></View>";
```

Hope this helps, happy coding...